# Public hotspot with advertisements

Tags: wifi, router, openwrt, transparentproxy, router-os

I would like to build a public wifi hotspot  on a openwrt router which interrupts user-surfing after about 15 minutes by showing a commercial. I think I need a transparent proxy to achieve this but dont know which one could do that. Could someone help me with that and give me a hint of the configuration?
Thank you in advance
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Look at nodogsplash package - it will get you started. Please note though, that this trick will not work with https sites - user will get security warnings instead of ads.